# $a^x+(a+b)^y=(a+c)^z$ then $(a,a+b,a+c)=1 \iff (b,c)=1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can it be shown that

Equation with $a,b,c,x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that

$$a^x+(a+b)^y=(a+c)^z$$

> Then $\gcd(a,a+b,a+c)=1 \iff \gcd(b,c)=1$

Example

$$\begin{split} 3^5+10^2 &=7^3\\ \to3^5+(3+7)^2 &=(3+4)^3\\ \implies\gcd(3,10,7)&=\gcd(7,4)=1\end{split}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $2^7+17^3=71^2$ (found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%E2%80%93Catalan_conjecture)), so $a=2,b=15,c=69,x=7,y=3,z=2$ is a counterexample.

Note however that one of the implications is true: if $a,a+b,a+c$ share a factor $d>1$, then $d$ also divides both $b$ and $c$. [Beal conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture) states that if we assume $x,y,z\geq 3$, then in any solution $a,a+b,a+c$ must share a factor, so under this extra assumption the answer to your question is (conjecturally) positive.

Comment: Thanks actually I already observe your statement in the morning but I thought given claim is more general. I'm also strongly believe given claim true for $x,y,z>2$